# What is causing this bug that only affects Android 8.0?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-8.0-oreo

this is my first post and I write it out of desperation (excuse me, my English is a translator) I created a small game in unity and it works quite well on Android all the verses except android 8, there is this error throwing me can you help me?

java.lang.RuntimeException:

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3303)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3411)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (Unknown Source)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1994)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7529)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:1081)

at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source:4)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7383)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1218)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3256)

Comment: Can you show your class code where you are getting this error?

Comment: That is all the information that the developer console gives me, so I do not know how to locate the fault (I am studying unity so my knowledge is not very advanced sorry)

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but the vanilla 8.0 source of `Activity.java` throws only an `IllegalStateException` at a single place, the line count doesn't quite match, but maybe it helps you to debug the issue further: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.0.0_r39/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#986

Comment: I have managed to remove the error by changing the target Api lvl from automatic (highest installed) to Api lvl 28, thank you very much for your answers !!